# Can I mount a share to an EMC array?

Tags: nfs, network-attached-storage, emc, synology

I would like to mount an NFS share to an EMC array enlarging it's capacity until we can expand the EMC environment.  I have a cheap Synology with 12TB of storage I would like to use to expand it for a short time.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Don't entertain this idea. If you need to expand the capacity of your EMC array (please specify the type), go through the proper channels and work with EMC on the possible upgrade paths. Running out of space wasn't a surprise, was it?

If you wish to use the Synology NAS as additional space, just use it as a standalone device; another tier of storage. The EMC will not be able to address the Synology in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need a [DAE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJTIl.jpg) from EMC to add more drives to a Clariion or VNX.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I didn't think it could, but I was hoping to have a faster solution then getting additional storage from EMC.  Then also recoding all the websites and servers accessing it.

Comment: Surely you didn't just wake up one morning and say "whoops, ran out of storage!" did you? Lead time on DAEs and disks from EMC is typically less than one week. If you need to expand your storage sooner than that, you've got some serious organizational issues internally that you should sort out.

Comment: It's for a client that we have inherited.  We're still learning how the web site works, nevermind how much storage we have.